# ckeditor destroyed my header

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, z-index, richtext

I have a fixed header similar to Facebook

[image]

But when I scroll down, the toolbox of the ckeditor will destroy my fixed header

[image]

Comment: add z-index "fixed header"

Comment: something like this?
`width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 background: #8b3131;
 box-shadow: 0.2px 0.2px 0.2px 0.2px #000000;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;`

Comment: Replace to  z-index: 9999;

Comment: its now ok. thanks a lot, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in Z-index

for the nav add

```
#Navbarclass { z-index:999; }
```

*replace `#Navbarclass` with your header class of ID